# How to transfer two datatable into gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

i want transfer 2 datatable to a gridview.
for example i have datatable1 and datatable2 and fill two datatable Now both of them fill in gridview.
please help me thanks.

for example

```
datatable dt1=new datatable();
datatable dt2=new datatable();
for(i=0;i<=8000;i++){
dt1.rows.add();
dt2.rows.add();
///fill both of them
}
gridview.datasource(dt1+dt2)//how can fill both of them
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataTable` class has a `Merge` method, which returns a new `DataTable` that you can use as your datasource:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx

Comment: thats good,in my software i have 1000000000 record in DB and i use linq to sql,my DB Encryption and  I should think decode my information,i decode my info and datable but datatable limitation 16000000 record!now i want use datatable 2 and fill into gridview

Comment: I would question why you want to put over 16m rows into a gridview. It hints at a more fundamental problem with your data handling.

Comment: thanks for solution.i find solve!

Answer (score 0):

U can show it by using SoredProcedure in DB...

or

see the following link 
http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/database/add-data-to-gridview-from-multiple-tables-in-asp-net-4-0-and-c/